# Values of Cartesian coordinates for dimensions higher then the dimensionality of the communicator in MPI_Cart_coords()

Tags: mpi

The `MPI_Cart_coords()` function has the following prototype:

```c
 int MPI_Cart_coords(MPI_Comm comm, int rank, int maxdims, int *coords);
```

The `maxdims` argument specifies the size of the `coords[]` array. Of course, it is possible that the number of dimensions in `comm` (let's denote that value as `n`) is less than `maxdims`: `n < maxdims`.

My question is what does MPI standard say about values of `coords[n]` ... `coords[maxdims-1]` after the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I opened the report for you and used the search function of my PDF reader for you. It doesn't actually specify anything. Only when `n==0` the array `coords` is unchanged.

Just open http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf and search for `MPI_CART_COORDS`.

Comment: So, that is not specified, is it?
My understanding is that we can not assume the values to be neither changed nor unchanged.